# Problem with real time notification with laravel echo and pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I used Laravel Echo and Pusher for increment counter of notification in real time, it was working for a time but no it doesn't work anymore and i don't know the reason why ( the counter doesn't increment in real time, i need to refresh the page)

i changed my .env with id of pusher:

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu

i used in layout this trick in order to get the id of admin :

```
<script>
            window.User = {
                id: {{ optional(auth()->user())->id}}
            }
</script>
```

and in bootstrap.js :

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});


window.Echo.private('App.Models.User.' +User.id)
    .notification((notification) => {
        document.getElementById('js-count').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('js-count').innerHTML) + 1;
    });
```

Comment: Tip: Did you inspect using developer tools in chrome (or another browser with debugging tools)? You can view your websocket requests right there.

Comment: Hi, there is no error in console! how should i inspect ? what exactely ?

Comment: Ah maybe I was not clear, for chrome: open dev tools, tab network and inside that you have another tab labeled `ws` for websockets. There you should see another tab (yes 3 levels of tabs already) with messages. Maybe you can see if there is something interesting in there.

Comment: This is the error.   {event: "pusher:error",…}
data: {code: null, message: "Invalid key in subscription auth data: 'defa098d509bf4b72857'"}
event: "pusher:error"                                                                                                                I don't understand the problem: i verify the keys and there is no error, i generate other keys but same problem